# Wordpress Cron Job 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm running a cron job, to insert a properties from a Prop-Space API,

I'm using **wp_insert_post** method to insert properties in the wp_post table, but after 150 Insertion my server crashed and say 500 Internal Server error. Script is running fine on localhost can any one have a solution for this ?

Comment: You have a programming error(same style as your question).

Answer (score 0):

If its timeout issue, then adding following lines in your cron job file might be helpful

```
ini_set( "display_errors", 1);
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```